# Angular routerLink on *ngFor checkboxes

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have a list of checkboxes created with *ngFor. When the user select a checkbox, I display under the list another component. I've put routerLink on every checkbox basically, becase when the user clicks on a checkbox, the url should be updated with checkbox's id. The problem is that when I uncheck the checkbox, I want my checkbox's id to be remove from URL. How can I do that? I have something basic:

```
<span class="example-list-section">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let subtask of task.subtasks">
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="subtask.completed"
                       routerLink="{{subtask.id}}">
          {{subtask.name}}
        </mat-checkbox>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in a case `subtask.id` is empty, you can set `routerLink` value as `[]`, so that it won't redirect anywhere.

```
[routerLink]="subtask.id ? [subtask.id]: ['']"
```

Comment: It's not my case. A subtask always has an id. When I select a checkbox (the URL gets updated with the id) and it's okay. The problem is that when I Uncheck the checkbox, I want the id to be removed from URL. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @denisiulian I'm sorry, can you please explain with an example. I think, I still don't get it. Perhaps I'm missing major context

Comment: Actually is working, but instead of [''] I've put the path to parent's route and I changed the conditional. Thank you! :)

Comment: Great, I'm happy that it helped and worked :) Happy Coding !!